# radio button return undefined value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Radio button is returning undefined value. my html code is :

```
  <input name="start" value="" id="start1" type="radio">
  <label for="start1">date</label>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        if (document.getElementById('start1').checked) {
            var CurrentDate = new Date();
            CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1);
        }
    });

</script>
```

when i check radio button start1 , then it will add 1 month to the current month. but my **console.log(CurrentDate)** shows undefined variable name. how can i show the result?

Comment: Looks like you need to attach an event listener. At the moment, you only have an unused function expression.

Comment: If you don't know what an "event listener" is, read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).

Comment: checkboxes will suit you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call the wrapper function

```js
(function () {
    document.getElementById('start1').addEventListener('change', () => {
        let CurrentDate = new Date();
        CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1);
        dateEl.innerHTML = CurrentDate
    })
})();
```

```html
<input name="start" value="" id="start1" type="radio">
<label for="start1">date</label>

<div id="dateEl"></div>
```

Comment: how can I use if statement here? because in my html file i have some radio button with different id name. @Илья Зеленько

Comment: I do not understand a bit, how exactly do you need to use `if`? do you want to display the date in another element?

Comment: yes and the date function will be different. @Илья Зеленько

Comment: [it looks like this is exactly what you need
:](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/NBVrxQ?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an [immediately-invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which runs as soon as it is defined - so it's going to run before you even have a chance to click on the radio button.

You need to attach an event listener to your radio button so that your function runs when the radio is clicked (or changed) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

Simple JavaScript -

```js
function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('start1').checked) {
        var CurrentDate = new Date();
        CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1);
        document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = ""+CurrentDate;
    }
};
```

```html
<input name="start" value="" id="start1" type="radio" oninput="check()">
<div id="dateDisplay"></div>
```